# Issues with forecasting model fit

Tags: r, forecasting, model-fitting

I want to forecast rainfall in Albury. I have a data set holding rainfall in mm from 2009 to 2016. Besides rainfall the data set holds other variables: date, windgustspeed, windspeed, humidity, maximum temperature, and pressure. All of these have in earlier tests shown to have influence on rainfall.

I have tried forecasting rainfall the next year using arima, vector autogressive, tslm, snaive, naive, mean, rw models. All of them seem only to forecast a mean and do not catch all.

Code used for model fitting

```
albury_fit <- albury %>%
  model(
    naive = NAIVE(Rainfall),
    drift = RW(Rainfall ~ drift()),
    mean = MEAN(Rainfall),
    seasonal_naive = SNAIVE(Rainfall),
    tslm = TSLM(Rainfall ~trend()),
    arima = ARIMA(Rainfall)
  )

albury_fc <- albury_fit %>%
  forecast(h = '1 year')
```

[image]plot of model fit

Code for checking model performance for arima, all models have the same output as arima

```
albury%>%
  model(ARIMA(Rainfall)) %>%
   gg_tsresiduals()
```

[image]output from the code above

So the bottom line is, that the models do not perform well, but I don't know how to fix it.
I hope that someone can help me :)

Comment: Are you only using the previous values of rainfall to forecast future rainfall?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the previous values to forecast future rainfall. I'm using the whole data set to forecast values not inside the data set.

Comment: Ok. This question is probably better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as it is not really related to programming.